Vimeo vs HTML 5 video for embedding a background video
I realise this is a repeat of Adding Video To Website - Embed or Vimeo? but 12 years is a long time on the net.
I have a video that is used as a full screen background and is around 50mb. Vimeo delivers this in 4-5mb chunks but uses a fair amount of Javacript to do it.
We don't need to leverage Vimeo sharing.
so for performance (read Lighthouse/SEO) is it best to embed HTM5 or a vimeo iframe?

Have you looked into how that video is compressed?  For a background image is seems massive.  I recently helped a client with buffering issues on their site, and it was because videos had not been properly compressed for the web.    I wonder if this is part of your problem.  As far as Lighthouse/SEO performance goes - at 50 megs - forget it.  Maybe you can offset some of the damage by deferring loading and/or enabling it only for desktop.

@davidgo Although it's literally in the background, it's a narrative video of around 2 minutes.

50 megs for a 2 minute video that runs in the background?  Thats wacko high. I'd have thought it should be 1/5th that or less - even if it ran in the foreground.

@davidgo I've done a bit of research and the lowest estimate I can find for 1080p is using H.264 (AVC), H.265 (HEVC) or VP9 at 4–5 Mbps ( Suitable for general streaming, balancing quality and file size ). Approx. 30–37.5 MB per minute.
Are you saying this is wrong?

I can't definitely say its right or wrong - but I question the need for 1080p for a background video.  I put to you the appropriate bitrate is significantly impacted by the type of video, with talking heads for example requiring a lot less bandwidth then highly dynamic scenes).  That said, I misspoke/misremembered - the  bitrate/filesize -  The videos I did for a client had a bitrate ranging from 1.2 - 2.5Mbps - about 1/3rd of your bitrate - and that was using H.264 which quite a bit bigger then  h.265 but has better browser support.  FYI, these videos were 1080p @ 25fps including sound.

Have you tried playing around with ffmpeg compression using CRF with various values to see where your sweet spot is?

I will. I think I'm not explaining the context properly. 'background' implies a lack of focus but that's really not the case here. I think I have to suppress the vimeo script loading until later in the process and get rid of the video on mobile

I'm going to approach this from a non-SEO perspective and more of a site admin POV. If you average 1K users a month to your site and you are serving this video to users (no caching anywhere for worst case), that is 6.25GB of bandwidth you will have to serve and this is only to load that video; nothing else.
That is a lot of bandwidth to serve just for a background video. I would question whether it is truly needed for the experience and if a static image would be better. More than likely a user won't sit there and see the entire video anyway. If it is needed, then maybe reduce the video to something more manageable. Even with a reduced filesize, I would think putting that strain on your bandwidth would put a serious hurt on your pocketbook.
From a performance perspective, I would suspect that a streaming service could handle the video better than your webserver and or CDN but you but you will definitely need to run the parameter that removes the player controls.
This would definitely be a situation where I would run both in a test environment and see which performs best; run a Lighthouse on both approaches.

Another thing to remember, your users on metered connections (e.g. 4G), how angry do you think they would be if they knew you were trying to serve a 50MB video on their metered connection? Not only do you need to think about the UX of the page, but the entire user as a whole.

this is true but our experience is that users don't hang around on the front page, and we are strictly B2B

You make some good points, my opinion is that we should stick with Vimeo not only on grounds of bandwidth but also that their feed is configured as a media server and does a lot of stuff we would struggle with (for instance the chunks I'm getting today are 2mb whereas the other day when my connection was faster I was getting 5mb chunks and a higher resolution video.

You are also correct that UX and performance are key here, SEO is broadly irrelevant. Our home page is not SEO rich, our efforts are much more focussed further in.
